# RxJS Filter Operator Acting Weird

Tags: rxjs

#### Here is my code:

- functional is about: ***ratelimiting*** something

#### Prerequisite

- RxJs version : `6.7.7`
- Typescript version : `3.4.5`

  - compilerOptions.targe: `es5`

```js
function factory(limit: number, period: number) {
    let count = limit;
    let token = new BehaviorSubject(count);

    let availableTokens = token.pipe(
        filter((v) => v > 0), // weird
        tap((v) =>
            `current emit value is ${v}, current BehaviorSubject value is ${token.getValue()}`,
            ),
        ),
        // filter(() => count > 0), // acting what i expected
        take(1),
    );

    return function (fn: number) {
        return availableTokens.pipe(
            map(() => {
                token.next(--count);
                timer(period).subscribe(() => token.next(++count));
                return fn;
            }),
        );
    };
}
// created a ratelimiter 
// rate: 5 times / 1000 ms
let rateLimiter = factory(5, 1000);
// testing
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    rateLimiter(i).subscribe({
        next: (v) => console.log(v),
    });
}
```

#### Expected

- First Second Output: `0 1 2 3 4`
- Second Second Output: `5 6 7 8 9`
- Third Second Output: `10 11 12 13 14`
- Fourth Second Output: `15 16 17 18 19`

#### Actually

- First Second Output: `0 1 2 3 4`
- Second Second Output: `5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19`

#### If using `filter(() => count > 0)` instead

- Behave exactly what i expected

#### Tap Operator Tap For Debug Log

```
current emit value is 5, current BehaviorSubject value is 5
current emit value is 4, current BehaviorSubject value is 4
current emit value is 4, current BehaviorSubject value is 4
current emit value is 3, current BehaviorSubject value is 3
current emit value is 3, current BehaviorSubject value is 3
current emit value is 2, current BehaviorSubject value is 2
current emit value is 2, current BehaviorSubject value is 2
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is 1
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is 1
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is 1
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is 0
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -1
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -2
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -3
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -4
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -5
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -6
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -7
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -8
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -9
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -10
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -11
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -12
current emit value is 1, current BehaviorSubject value is -13
```

#### Why ???

- `tap` log : emit value !== count
- I suppose these two should be equal

Comment: I think you'll need to simplify this example because I have no idea what is this supposed to do. There're recursive calls so it's very hard to understand. I'm suspicious that this has something to do with calling `consume();` inside `mergeMap()` becaue in RxJS everything is synchronous. Maybe try using `delay(0)` instead of the commented line. If this helps then the issue is really in expecting async behavior from sync code.

Comment: I  tried. `delay(0)` using instead of the commented line. The same problem.

Comment: Thx for the comment. And I simplify as much as I can.

Comment: I may found the werid part. But still don't know why.

Comment: What is your goal with the rate limiter function? How is it supposed to be used in practice? It's not clear to me how I could use this to rate-limit something else.